# How to Properly Get Jquery Datatable Server Side Parameters in Express js Route

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, datatables

I am working on implementing server-side datatables in a node.js app using expressjs as my routing.   My datatable configuration:

```
$('#sitesTable').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '/site/fragments/siteList/filter',
    order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
    pageLength: 10,
    columns: [
        { title: 'SID', data: 'ID' },
        { title: 'Store', data: 'Name'},
        (several other columns here)
    ]
});
```

In my route (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320495/express-js-4-json-parsing-problems-from-get-request-request-data-from-datatable) and other resources I found while researching this)

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router({
   strict: true
});

var url = require('url');

router.get('site/fragments/siteList/filter', function(req, res) {
   debug('Filtered Sites query');
   var queryString = url.parse(req.url, true);
   var myFoo = queryString.query;

   console.log(myFoo);
});
```

When this request is run, the following gets output to console:

```
{ draw: '1',
    'columns[0][data]': 'ID',
    'columns[0][name]': '',
    'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[0][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[0][search][value]': '',
    'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
    'columns[1][data]': 'Name',
    'columns[1][name]': '',
    'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[1][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[1][search][value]': '',
    'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
    'order[0][column]': '0',
    'order[0][dir]': 'asc',
    start: '0',
    length: '10',
    'search[value]': '',
    'search[regex]': 'false'
}
```

Note that the array parameters (columns & search) are not parsed properly.   How can I properly parse the request to obtain the separate parameters in a useable format?

Comment: Even I have the same problem.
If you have solved it, Can you post the solution?